# Tomcat - multiple users getting same sessionID

Tags: tomcat, cas

I am trying to troubleshoot a problem. A user logged into an application using CAS SSO. This user was logged into a different user’s account - usually to a users account that logged in seconds before. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening and how to solve it?

We did put in a temp workaround, which is just to bounce the web servers once a week in a rotational manner to clear out all sessions. This seems to prevent it from every getting to the point to where this problem occurs. Of course we don't want this as the permanent solution.

This systems runs Apache Tomcat 8.0.15 and CAS version 3.6

We are about to upgrade Tomcat to 8.5.35 and maybe that fixes it, but we prefer the piece of mind of proof. So far we have not found anything in the release notes or bug fixes that we felt was an exact match to the problem we are seeing. As such, we also don't want to rule out a possible configuration error at this time.

So if anyone has any suggestions to the cause or even better have seen this before and know what fixed it for you, please share.

The error message that we found is the following:

05-Dec-2018 13:51:07.477 SEVERE [catalina-exec-149] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [cas] in context with path [/cas] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException

It appears to us that it can no longer get a sessionID and instead of not allowing a new session, it just reuses the previous active sessionID. Sounds like a bug, but again haven't found definitive proof of it being fixed in the release we are upgrading too.

Below is an entry from the access logs of a user whose jsessionid was reused causing unauthorized access. IPs and other identifiable information in the logs below have been changed on purpose.

Please see how two different IPs both received the same sessionID

185.226.72.189 **5D508C736DFACC38B405A5F9B2C61BBC** - [11/Dec/2018:18:07:00 -0500] GET /cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fsed.instructure.com%2Flogin%2Fcas HTTP/1.1 200 5831 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36 -

- c-97-98-201-15.hsd1.ca.comcast.net **5D508C736DFACC38B405A5F9B2C61BBC** - [11/Dec/2018:18:07:04 -0500] POST /cas/login;jsessionid=5D508C736DFACC38B405A5F9B2C61BBC?service=https%3A%2F%2Fsed.instructure.com%2Flogin%2Fcas HTTP/1.1 302 - https://cas.mydomain.com/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fsed.instructure.com%2Flogin%2Fcas Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there's an over-eagerly caching reverse proxy somewhere in the path, on any of those sides. You don't mention it, but most of the times that I've seen this scenario, that was the cause.

Just to be sure: Tomcat 8.0.15 has been released 4 years ago, and Tomcat 8.0 has reached its [end of life](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-80-eol.html) in June 2018 - you might also want to make sure that you got all security fixes and update to 8.5 or 9.0, especially as you're asking about a security issue here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Olaf. We don't actually have proxies in this environment.

Comment: Are you sure? This could also be CDN servers outside of your immediate influence. Look up the IP that your browser connects to, and validate that it's the IP you expect your tomcat to have - otherwise, you'll have found the system that you'll need to check.